How to change server running on localhost to online in React/Node.js project with MongoDB Atlas?
I am currently creating my own React + Node.js project, and using MongoDB as my database. It nicely provides HTTP endpoints that I am using to get data. My project structure is as follows:
my-project/
  |- server/
     |- index.js
     |- package.json
  |- src/
     |- index.js
     |- App.js
  |- package.json

In my root level package.json, these are the configurations:
{
  "name": "tutorsync",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "mongoose": "^8.3.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "^1.11.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel start-react start-serv er",
    "start-react": "react-scripts start",
    "start-server": "node server/index.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  }
}

In my server side package.json, these are my configurations:
{
    "name": "backend",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
      "cors": "^2.8.5",
      "express": "^4.19.2",
      "mongoose": "^8.3.0"
    }
  }

I am connecting to the MongoDB using mongoose, and creating an endpoint of my own /api/getAllStudents. This works well (following is the code in my server side index.js):
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dbUrl =
  "mongodb+srv://<myrealusername>:<mypassword>@cluster0.xuzk1ah.mongodb.net/Tuition?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0";
const connectionParams = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
};
const axios = require("axios");
mongoose
  .connect(dbUrl, connectionParams)
  .then(() => {
    console.info("Connected to the DB");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("Error", e);
  });

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

app.get("/api/getAllStudents", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const url =
      "https://ap-southeast-1.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-piopg/endpoint/students";

    const apiKey = <hidden>;

    axios
      .get(url, {
        headers: {
          "api-key": apiKey,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Response:", response.data);
        res.status(200).json(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});

In my App.js for the frontend part, I am trying to use axios to fetch data using this endpoint that I created /api/getAllStudents and my current code snippet in App.js which works is:
axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/api/getAllStudents")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));

The issue is that I don't want to use localhost, because I want others to be able to use it as well (access database, edit entries there etc.). But I have trouble figuring out what URL to use when using axios. I am hosting my application using Vercel.
I tried doing axios.get("/api/getAllStudents") without the localhost but it gives me a 404 error. I also tried doing axios.get("<my vercel deployed app url>/api/getAllStudents") but it similarly does not work. Only axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/getAllStudents") works and that is only when I run my project locally.
I have tried googling this but I think I am not looking in the correct direction. I would appreciate if someone could point out what I am missing and how I can replace my URL so that others can use this app, or at least provide some direction to look into. Thank you in advance!

As far as I know, Vercel is used to deploy frontend applications, not node backend.
